# Goodix I2C Touchscreen recognised as a keyboard

Tags: drivers, xorg, touchscreen, acpi, i2c

I have an "Iota flo 360" laptop running ubuntu studio 22.04LTS on which the touchscreen doesn't work. It's a cheap Celeron based machine, I have it dual booting and the touchscreen works on Windows 10.
The default ubuntu studio install has X11 running not wayland.

`uname -a`

> Linux iotaflo360 5.15.0-40-lowlatency #43-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 16 17:07:13 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The American Megatrends UEFI interface indicates it's an I2C device

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Touch Panel Device | Goodix GT9110P Touch Plane |
| Panel Gravity Sensor | Dual GSensor Address High |
| Gravity Sensor Flag Select | Flag 6 |
| Board Gravity Sensor | Board GSensor Address Low |
| Touch Pad Device | HTIX5288 TouchPad |
| Termination for I2C 5/6/7 | 1KOhms Pull Up |

I can do `modprobe goodix`

then dmesg contains

```
[    4.628437] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply AVDD28 not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.628487] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: supply VDDIO not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.629294] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: ID 927, version: 1040
[    4.633605] Goodix-TS i2c-GDIX1002:00: Invalid config (0, 0, 0), using defaults
[    4.633679] input: Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0/i2c_designware.4/i2c-4/i2c-GDIX1002:00/input/input6
```

Most strangely I can do `xinput` but it comes up as a keyboard.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HTIX5288:00 0911:5288 Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HTIX5288:00 0911:5288 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ icspring camera: icspring camer           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Goodix Capacitive TouchScreen             id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput test 15` shows no output when I touch the screen.

What can I try next?